# the confuse of 'nn' , 'dp' and 'dpnn' module in Torch

Tags: torch

When i read some torch codes, i was confused with the "nn" and "dp" model. I see in many codes which requires only  dp (no nn), but why it can use nn.methodA? why it can use nn without require it ? besides, the method is defined in the dpnn!  Should it be used as dpnn.methodA?  the codes do like this:

```
   require 'dp'
   ...
   nn.methodA() [the methodA is defined in 'dpnn']
```

Answer (score 2):

'dp' has 'nn' as a dependency, and requires 'nn'. More specifically when calling `require 'dp'` the init script of 'dp' is run. This calls `require 'dpnn'` ([see](https://github.com/nicholas-leonard/dp/blob/master/init.lua)). Subsequently the init script of 'dpnn' is run and calls `require 'nn'` ([see](https://github.com/Element-Research/dpnn/blob/master/init.lua)).

Additionally, modules share the same global namespace. This means modules can set abc or nn or whatever. Many modules extend the namespace of 'nn' to include extra functionality.

Comment: thanks,  so how to extend the namespace of 'nn', is there any keywords used in the codes?

Comment: As they are extensions to the 'nn' package it looks much cleaner and understandable to put them in the same namespace. This also somewhat indicates they are compatible, and are all extensions of nn.Module.

Comment: See https://github.com/Element-Research/dpnn/blob/master/Inception.lua#L18
Basically `module, parent = torch.class('nn.ModuleName', 'nn.Parent')`

Comment: 1 what do you mean by extensions to 'nn' package?  the dpnn just require 'nn' in its init file , so we can say module A is an extension to module B if A  require B in its init file？   
   
2 what this code mean ： module,parent=torch.class('nn.ModuleName','nn.Parent')?  i can only know it init two class ie. module and parent ? how can we know we can use nn.methodA as methodA is defined in dpnn from it?

Comment: Oh, i know, So the module, parent = torch.class('nn.ModuleName', 'nn.Parent')   assign the method with the name nn.ModuleName, and we can visit it anywhere?

Comment: 'dpnn' not only requires 'nn', but adds additional functions that are not available in 'nn', that is what I mean by extends. And to your second question it assigns `module` with the name `nn.ModuleName`, and inherits all the functionality of `nn.Parent`. See Inheritance in Lua: http://www.lua.org/pil/16.2.html, and have a look at torch.class https://github.com/torch/class